# Getting the duration of an mp3 on a website

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, naudio

I'm using NAudio.Wave in my Xamarin Forms app. I have an mp3 file stored both on the device and can get the duration quite simply using NAudio. However, I also have an mp3 file on my website and need to find the duration of the mp3 file.

Can I use NAudio.Wave to find the length of the mp3 without downloading the file itself?

Comment: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/PlayAudioFromUrl.md

Comment: I'll give that a shot

Comment: Looks like that relies on MediaFoundation which isn't supported in Xamarin

Comment: You have to have access to the file's contents to figure out duration. File size plus known bitrate will get you close, but VBR/ABR or large ID3 data chunks will interfere with the process. Either way you'll need to read at least the file header to figure it out.